# Solve $\ln {x^2} = 2\ln 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Solve the equation $\ln {x^2} = 2\ln 4$

What follows is my approach to the problem. I would appreciate any pointers on what is wrong with it.

\begin{align}
\ln x^2 & = 2 \ln 4 \\
2 \ln x & = 2 \ln 4 &&\text{$\log_a b^c = c\log_a b$} \\
\ln x & = \ln 4 \\
x & = 4
\end{align}

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: $x$ can be negative, $\ln x^2=2\ln|x|$.

Comment: @Yves It can also be complex, so what? The point is, the OP did not explicitly say where $x$ can come from. And so I have to make an implicit assumption. For me, $x \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is more natural than $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: the OP is explicitly asking what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotcha!
\begin{align}
\ln x^2 & = 2 \ln 4 \\
\ln |x|^2 & = 2 \ln 4 \\
2 \ln |x| & = 2 \ln 4
\end{align}

Comment: That was enlightening :)

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct, but not complete.

Following your approach: $$\ln x^2=\ln 4^2$$
$$x^2=16,$$

which has two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the solution $x=-4$. Here are the steps:
$$\ln x^2=2\ln 4 = \ln 4^2 \Longrightarrow x^2 = 4^2 \Longrightarrow x = \pm 4 $$